# Single time omit field while saving to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Scenario: I have `User` entity, I create user where password is encoded by `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. Then I have form which edit my `User`. I'm doing it this way:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
@SessionAttributes("userForm")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEditUserForm(@PathVariable("userId") long userId, 
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", userService.findUserById(userId));
    return "userEdit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") User 
        userForm, BindingResult bindingResult,
        @PathVariable("userId") long userId, Model model, SessionStatus status) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "userEdit";
    } else {
        userService.save(userForm);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/users/" + userId;
    }
}
```

Problem: When I submit edit form, my password changes and I can't login to my account. Is there any way to save `User` excluding e.g. username and password fields? Or maybe is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there is a design issue with your database i.e., your database design has mixed up both the security details with other details.

To solve the issue by keeping the existing design, you can use the below approach, but I strongly recommend to separate the data out.

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
   return "userEdit";
} else {
    User userDB = userService.findUserById(userId);
    //compare the new & db values 
    //i.e., userForm and userDB and then update to userDB
    //userDB.setX(userForm.getX());
    //IGNORE PWD FIELDS, DO NOT UPDATE THEM TO userDB object
    userService.save(userDB);
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/users/" + userId;
}
```

Also, I recommend **not fetching security details (like passwords, etc..) from the database unless they are absolutely required for the View**.

> It populates anyway while initializing userForm in GET method. It
>   takes password from database, I'm looking for solution, to still use
>   User as form but avoid interfering with the passw.

The other simplest option is **you can UPDATE the specific fields i.e., excluding password** by writing an HQL query (in Hibernate)

Comment: So maybe there is some better approach to editing User details instead working on object from DB?

Comment: You can keep the object inside `HttpSession`, but I suggest NOT to do that because the data is sensitive

Comment: I have my `User` in session. Everything works properly except this password :/ `PasswordEncoder` hashes again same password and I can't get to my account after it ( i think it works this way :P ).

Comment: Comparing `userForm` with `userFromDB` doesnt help. Password is still encoded again and this new one is saved to DB :/

Comment: Don't populate the password from Form object

Comment: It populates anyway while initializing `userForm` in GET method. It takes password from database, I'm looking for solution, to still use `User` as form but avoid interfering with the passw.

Comment: You can look above

Comment: This is it! Totally forget about basics :D This whole ORM messed mi up tottaly :P! Thanks bro.